# The set of all $k$-dimensional planes which intersects $X$ is closed in $G(k,n)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

Let $X$ be irreducible algebraic set of projective n space.
I am trying to show that: The set of all $k$-dimensional planes which intersects $X$ is closed in $G(k,n)$, where $G(k,n)$ is the Grassmanian of the linear subspaces of dimension $k$ inside projective $n$ space.  I know the fact that $A=${$(H,x)$|$x$ belongs to  $H$} is closed in the direct product of $G(k,n) $ and the  projective $n$ space, where $H$ belongs to $G(k,n)$. Using the above known fact I am trying to show that : The set of all $k$-dimensional planes which intersects $X$ is closed in $G(k,n)$

Comment: I think we just have to prove that the projection map from direct product of $G(k,n)$ and the projective n space to $G(k,n)$ is a closed map. Is the projection map from direct product of projective $n$ space and projective $m$ space to projective $n$ space a closed map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The projection map from direct product of $G(k,n)$ and the projective $n$ space to $G(k,n)$ is a closed map since projective $n$ space is compact. Hence the result follows easily